# Python inner classes self

Tags: python

```py
class student :
    def __init__(self,name,rno) :
        self.name=name
        self.rno=rno
        self.Lap=self.Laptop

    def show(self) :
        print(self.name,self.rno)
        self.Lap.show()

    class Laptop:
        def __init__(self) :
            self.brand="hp"
            self.cpu="i5"
            self.ram=8

        def show(self):
            print(self.brand,self.cpu,self.ram) 

s1=student("ravi",2)
s2=student("kumar",3)
s1.show()
```

I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: show() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing brackets in your `student`'s class constructor:

```py
self.Lap=self.Laptop()
```

Comment: Thank you bro confused totally not remembered  can I contact you any id like email, fb, whatsapp please just need help some time because of started learning now only

Comment: @RavikumarMk glad I could help. Please, accept the answer and upvote if it helped you. You have my contact info on my profile [page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5517378/nutcracker?tab=profile)